# update panel, Refresh page while uploading file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload, updatepanel

I am working with Asp.Net FileUpload control with update panel,
    if i use the AsyncPostBackTrigger,i am unable to get the filename in server side,but if i use PostBackTrigger its working fine with page refreshing.
    my ASP.net code is:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers> 
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

I don't want to refresh page while uploading file.     
Please tell me.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FileUpload control will not work with Asynchronous postback and therefore it will not work from within an AJAX UpdatePanel. In case you use the FileUpload control within an UpdatePanel, You will still need a full postback. AsyncPostBackTrigger will not do the trick for a FileUpload control.

check the link,
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42865/AsyncFileUpload-Control-New-Control-in-Ajax-Contro